# Azure Function Queue triggered with Mediatr - DbContext error

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-functions, dbcontext, azure-functions-runtime, mediatr

I'm implementing Queue triggered azure function - I'm using a Mediator Pattern library called Mediatr for enhancing command query segregation - and using the latest run-time (2.0.12382.0) constructor dependency injection in Azure Function according to the following tutorial 
https://devkimchi.com/2019/02/22/performing-constructor-injections-on-azure-functions-v2/

For each Azure function trigger, I call a Mediatr `CommandHandler` but i'm receiving error :

> "A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext, however instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe. This could also be caused by a nested query being evaluated on the client, if this is the case rewrite the query avoiding nested invocations."

The error states that i'm trying to access the same instance of `DbContext` from parallel tasks. however I only have one command handler (Mediatr Handler) and one  Query Handler. and i'm using constructor injection for that

I tried to change the Meditr service to be transient in the startup , but still receive the same error on testing the function inside the azure function emulator

Startup Class

```
public class StartUp : IWebJobsStartup
{

    public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
             .AddEnvironmentVariables()
             .Build();
        var connection = configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"); 
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<CoreDBContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connection, p =>
            {
                p.MigrationsAssembly("B12Core.Persistence");
            });
        }
        );
        builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestPreProcessorBehavior<,>));
        builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestPerformanceBehaviour<,>));
        builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestValidationBehavior<,>));
        builder.Services.AddMediatR(p =>
        {
            p.AsTransient();

        }, typeof(CreateMessageCommand).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
    }
}
```

Full Error

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext, however instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe. This could also be caused by a nested query being evaluated on the client, if this is the case rewrite the query avoiding nested invocations.

Comment: I run into the same problem. Evidently scooped dependencies are still not working correctly.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3399#issuecomment-481448159

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing the db context injection lifetime to ServiceLifetime.Transient

```
 builder.Services.AddDbContext<CoreDBContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(connection, p =>
                {
                   p.MigrationsAssembly("Presistence");
                });
            },ServiceLifetime.Transient
            );
```